# I am trying to do a join in ruby with parameters. I am getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Controller code:

```
@fte_new_hires = Bvadmin::EmployeeApplicant.fte_new_hires(next_startdate, next_enddate)
```

Model code:

```
class Bvadmin::EmployeeApplicant < Bvadmin::Record
  self.table_name = "BVADMIN.EMPLOYEE_APPLICANTS"
  self.primary_key = :applicant_id
  has_many :employeeapplications

  scope :fte_new_hires, -> (startdate,enddate) {EmployeeApplicant.joins   (:employeeapplications).where("confirmed_eod >= ? and confirmed_eod <= ?", startdate, enddate).order('name ASC') }
end
```

Getting following error:

> uninitialized constant Bvadmin::EmployeeApplicant::EmployeeApplicant

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is 'Bvadmin::EmployeeApplicant', but you used 'EmployeeApplicant' in the scope, so it tried to find constant 'EmployeeApplicant' in this class 'Bvadmin::EmployeeApplicant', that is why you got 'uninitialized constant Bvadmin::EmployeeApplicant::EmployeeApplicant' error

```
 joins is equivalent to self.joins which is equivalent to Bvadmin::EmployeeApplicant.joins
```

self in this class is Bvadmin::EmployeeApplicant, so you can just do like below,

**Updated**

```
 scope :fte_new_hires, -> (startdate,enddate) {joins(:employee_applications).where("confirmed_eod >= ? and confirmed_eod <= ?", startdate, enddate).order('name ASC') }
```

Change your Association like below:

```
 has_many :employee_applications, class: "Bvadmin::EmployeeApplicantion"
```

Comment: I replaced this line, but when I try to do:

Comment: So my other model is: class Bvadmin::EmployeeApplication < Bvadmin::Record
  self.table_name = "BVADMIN.EMPLOYEE_APPLICATIONS"
  self.primary_key = :application_id
  belongs_to :employeeapplicant
end
Does the join line need to be:  scope :fte_new_hires, -> (startdate,enddate) {joins(:bvadmin::EmployeeApplications).where("confirmed_eod >= ? and confirmed_eod <= ?", startdate, enddate).order('name ASC') }

Comment: What is the error ? :bvadmin::EmployeeApplications is not an association, it should be joins(:employee_applications).  I have updated the association also in the code, may be that is the issue you have now.